# Alternative Orchard template for MenuItemLink

Tags: orchardcms

I'm creating a sub navigation widget called 'Callouts' that will show an image summary of each page it links to.

I want to change MenuItemLink.cshtml to include these images, but the only template I've found that I'm able to change based on the widget name is Widget-Name-Callouts.cshtml

There are several layers in between this and the template I want to change:

```
Widget-Name-Callouts.cshtml
@Display(Model.Content)

    Parts.MenuWidget.cshtml
    @Display(Model.Menu)

        Menu.cshtml
        ...
        @DisplayChildren(Model)
        ...

             MenuItemLink.cshtml
```

Is there a way to make a specific MenuItemLink template based on the widget it is contained in?

I'm displaying this menu twice and want to display the menu items differently in the different menu widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a module that adds an alternate template to MenuItemLink based on the zonename.

This module is in the Orchard Gallery:

**[MenuItemLink Alternates Module](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.NogginBox.MenuItemLinkAlternates)**

With this module you can create a theme template file called `MenuItemLink-ZoneName.cshtml`

Answer (score 0):

you can create alternate for only MenuItemLink. Install Designer tools module and enable shape tracing and widget alternates. You can create specific alternate for your menu item link. It is quite easy using the designer tools. 
http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Customizing-Orchard-using-Designer-Helper-Tools

Comment: Even when I enable Widget alternatives no template alternative is shown in the shape tracing tool that is specific to this widget. I can override MenuItemLink.cshtml but that affects all menu links and I only want it to affect the ones inside this widget.

Comment: You can give a name to menu shown in the widget. And then even if designer tool is not showing alternate, you can create alternate based on menu name. Like this (Refer Orchard alternates docs) for example:
MenuItemLink__[MenuName]. (Example template: MenuItemLink-main-menu)
MenuItemLink__[ContentType]. (Examples template: MenuItemLink-ContentMenuItem, MenuItemLink-HtmlMenuItem, MenuItemLink-Blog)

Comment: I don't want it based on the menu name. I'm using the same menu twice and I want to display it differently in just this widget.

Comment: @Richard, I forgot to mention, You should enable url alternates also. so if you are using same menu on different urls then, you can use url alternates.

Comment: Widget and url alternatives are both enabled. I've tried MenuItemLink-Name-Callouts.cshtml, but this isn't working.

Comment: Is "Name-Callouts" your menu name? MenuItemLink-[MenuName]-menu-url-[url].cshtml is a valid alternate, Which I am using currently.

Comment: I pointed out that I don't want to do it based on the menu name because I'm displaying the same menu twice. I'm trying to do it based on the widget name. I don't think this behaviour is standard out of the box and it will probably require something other than just naming the template right.